# Call url for on Delete button

Tags: python, flask

I have grid which users information and a button called Delete in each row.
I am trying to delete user from that grid on button click

I have created a route for this purpose

```
@app.route('/delete_user/<email>', methods=['POST','GET'])
def delete_user(email):
    table=db.users
    query=table.remove( {'email': email} )
    return render_template("index.html")
```

And in my template (index.html) file 
I have done this

```
{% for us in users %}
                  <tr>
                   <td>{{us['name']}}</td>
                  <td>{{us['email']}}</td>          
              <td><button type="button" onclick="url_for('delete_user',email={{us['email']}})" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

But It does not work.
Is there any other to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for( 'delete_user',email=us['email']) }}
```